# iOS: SwiftyJSON parsing from Alamofire is an array. Getting null when trying to parse

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

the api request returns something like this:

```
[  
   {  
  "
     .....
```

I am using swiftyJSON to parse this, I got data from Alamofire request:

```
let json = JSON(data)
let mapHeir = json[0]["Info"]["String"]
print(mapHeir)
```

This returns null, I tried:

```
let mapHeir = json[0]["Info"]["String"].string
let mapHeir = json[0]["Info"]["String"].stringValue
let mapHeir = json["Info"]["String"]
```

and all of them return empty.
How can I get to hatHierarchyString?

Comment: I need your complete JSON. Please paste it here so that we could help you further.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it. I just need to know how to get into an array and then to hatHeirarchyString.

Comment: Does your JSON begin exactly like this? Like **exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Suppose you've something like:

```
.responseJSON{ response in

switch response.result{
                    case .Success:
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
```

Then do,

```
if let someThing = json[0]["hatInfo"]["hatHierarchyString"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}
```

Comment: Anytime. Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over array first - in your case you have an array of dictionaries. Then access to dictionary data like this:

```
let mapHeir = json["hatInfo","hatHierarchyString"].stringValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
let string = json.array?.first?["hatInfo"]["hatHierarchyString"].string
```

This returns an optional `String`.

Comment: This gives me nil.